# is it possible to differentiate between different boundaries by use of bwboundaries in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a grey scale image in which there are black, grey and white regions, what I am trying to do is finding the length and position of each boundary. function bwboundaries is working just fine, however I wanted to ask if there is a way to differentiate between different boundaries, for example if there is a way to group boundaries between black/grey, white/grey, and black/white separately.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bwboundaries` automatically converts your image to binary so you cannot find white/grey boundaries with it directly.

Create three binary images from your image:

```
I1 = I>0; %both white/grey are 1, black is 0
I2 = I==gvalue; %grey = 1, rest 0
I3 = I==wvalue; %white = 1, rest 0
```

Then if you take BW boundaries for each of these images (call them `B1, B2, B3`) you'll end up with something like the below very simple example:

[image: output of bwboundaries]

From this it is (I hope) visually intuitive that the boundary between black and white, excluding any boundaries with grey, is found in the intersection of B1, and B3 (right hand side images), and so on.

How to efficiently locate these intersections is another matter, and might also depend if you know the nature of your image - e.g. are white and grey objects usually separated, overlapping - is it possible to have a grey object entirely surrounded by white, and so on.  At the most basic, you could loop through the various boundaries found and use `intersect` and/or `setdiff`.  One issue is that with this method, the boundaries in B2/B3 which should be the white/grey boundary are offset from each other by one pixel, so I found one way for this very simplified case was:

```
%Determine the grey/black and white/black intersections:
B_gb = intersect(B1{1},B2{1},'rows');
B_wb = intersect(B1{1},B3{1},'rows');

%Set the white/grey intersection using setdiff and one of the boundaries we just found
B_gw = setdiff(B2{1},B_gb,'rows');
```

[image]

For the larger scale case, I suggest first determining which (if any) boundaries are completely replicated in any two of your three boundary sets. This will be the case if, for example, you had a white region against a black background not overlapping with any grey regions.

---

Looking at your actual image, an alternate option is, having got your three binary images, to use a edge finder like canny.  This won't give you the length of individual boundary segments, though.

`BW1 =  edge(I1,'canny');` % etc for all three

Then the three sets of edges (w/b, g/b, w/g) can be found by:

`GB = BW2&BW3;` %etc for all three

Since these are just BW images, positions for plotting can be extracted with:

`[y x] = find(GB);` % and repeat

Final result: 
[image: edge finder using canny]

Comment: I first want to thank you for your great help.Actually, I still have some problems and hoping that I could get some more help. As you suggested I have used 'bwboundaries' and 'intersect', however I have noticed that while it works for corners of the image, in the center, I have no intersection.  I could not copy my code due to character limitations, so I am copying the links for the original image: http://i44.tinypic.com/2lu711t.jpg[/IMG]  and the resultant image: http://i42.tinypic.com/34dhfms.jpg[/IMG]...thank you again...

Comment: It's possible that the boundaries do not exactly overlap (so you have boundaries 1 pixel apart which intersect will not detect). An alternative option would be to use edge detection - I'll update.